# Looping through JSON data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, post

I'm building an array of image filesnames (src) and the ID attribute (id)

```
var arr = {};
$('.selection .image').each(function(index) {
    var $this = $(this),
    id = $this.children('img').attr('id'),
    src = $this.children('img').attr('src');

    arr[id] = src;
});
```

Then I'm sending it out to a php script to perform some other functions.

e.g. {"8":"http://www.domain.com/file8.jpg","9":"http://www.domain.com/file9.jpg"}

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'array.php',
    data: 'array='+JSON.stringify(arr),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        updateContainer(data.reply);
    },
});
```

I'm having trouble looping through the data in the php file. Can anyone help me further than this? Cheers

```
$json = $_POST['arr'];
$array = json_decode($json, TRUE);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be making this more complex then you need to. The `$.ajax` method will take an object for data:

```
data: arr
```

Then, on the PHP end you'd have the following:

```
print_r($_POST);

array(
  [8] => http://www.domain.com/file8.jpg
  ... etc ...
)
```

That being said, if you're sample code above is correct, you're passing in a value for `array` and trying to access it was `arr` on the php side. You'd  want `$_POST['array']` based on the code samples above, if you wish to say with the JSON method you've described.

Comment: Great, that has helped me out a lot!